# Unable to Install HP Printer (Moving this to my regular account)

Tags: printing

I have tried to install my HP Laserjet 1020 On Ubuntu 13.10 And it says installing plugin then nothing happends. it detects it and all but nothing works. I tried multple guides online but nothing fixes it whatsoever

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You need to install HPLIP driver.**

This driver can be download from Sourceforge via [HP website](http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/install_wizard/index.html).

To download and install follow this commands.

```
cd ~/Downloads

sudo wget -c "http://kaz.dl.sourceforge.net/project/hplip/hplip/3.13.11/hplip-3.13.11.run"

sudo sh hplip-3.13.11.run
```

** There is a nice GUI application called **hplip-gui** . It is a versatile tool. Even you can **Fax** using All-In-One printers with this application.

```
sudo apt-get install hplip-gui
```

Answer (score 1):

Strangely, the current version of hplip (3.14.3) doesn't include a ppd file for the 1010/1012 printers.  This is odd, because the installer offers the 1012 as one of the options prior to the make/install steps.

I got it working by downloading the ppd from [here](https://www.openprinting.org/ppd-o-matic.php?driver=pxl1010&printer=HP-LaserJet_1012&show=0) and copying it (sudo required) to `/usr/share/ppd/HP`

One other note: the HPLIP toolbox is really useful, but it's hard to find: look in *System Tools → Preferences*, if you're a Gnome user.