# How can I use a printer

Tags: printing

A new HP envy 4500 printer will print on Windows XP but not on Ubuntu 12.10. How can I fix it? I have unplugged and replugged the power and the USB connector and played the DVD  that came with the printer. When I send a selection to the printer it displays "now printing in the display on the printer but it  doesn't print.

It printed a test file once immediately after I set it up.Then it stopped printing

Comment: you must install the drivers

Answer (score 0):

You might try hplip -- I installed it via synaptic and it help solve some of my new HP printer problems.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You could try installing CUPS which allows you to manage and install printers.

```
sudo apt-get install cups
```

After installation complete, go to your web broser and type localhost:631

This will take you to CUPS page and guide you to the process of installing the printer.  After that use CUPS page to manage printers and jobs.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Follow [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/372587/224082) or [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/389206/224082) answers to install HPLIP (HP Linux Imaging and Printing) Drivers.