# HP Printer does not scan any document in ubuntu

Tags: installation, hp, scanner

I am using ubuntu 11.10 for last 2 or 3 days.
I like it. Now problem is that, When I installed my printer HP F2180 on ubuntu. It prints very well in ubuntu.but, I cannot scan any type of document through this printer in ubuntu.While in my other windows PC, The printer works very well. It prints good and also scan very well. In ubuntu, Where can i find the option for scanning the document via my printer. I am new to ubuntu or linux world. Please give me answer with full instrunction.
Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Install HPLIP Drivers. (HP Linux Imaging and Printing)

```
sudo apt-get install hp-ppd hpijs hpijs-ppds hplip hplip-cups hplip-data hplip-dbg hplip-doc hplip-gui printer-driver-postscript-hp
```

Certain applications may not available for 11.10. Remove the 'not found' applications and again run the command.

Or you can follow [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/372587/224082) answer to download drivers from Sourceforge.